# Elasticseatch переиндексация без простоя

Tags: elasticsearch

Как правильно выполнить полную переиндексацию в elasticsearch, чтобы пользователи не заметили? Например поменялся поменялась схема данных и нужно перестроить mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Повнимательней погуглил и нашел ответ здесь
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index-aliases.html#index-aliases